# Different robots.txt content for different domain names linked to the same root folder

Tags: dns, robots.txt

I have two domain names that link to one and the same root. How can I make robots.txt have different content depending on domain name?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write your own server script (like on PHP) and add redirect to .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Another way for multiple domains on same server

#### `.htaccess`

```bash
#load php file
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ "\/robots.php" [L]
```

#### PHP file `robot.php`

```php
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    // default path  
    $path = "./robots.txt";
    
    if ( preg_match("/domainname_one/i",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ) {
        $path = "./domainname_one_folder/robots.txt";
    }
    if ( preg_match("/domainname_two/i",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ) {
        $path = "./domainname_two_folder/robots.txt";
    }
    if ( preg_match("/domainname_three/i",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ) {
        $path = "./domainname_two_folder/robots.txt";
    }
    echo file_get_contents( $path );
?>
```